# Typo3: unset padding

Tags: css, cell, padding, typo3

I have a reset.css file which sets table cells padding to 0. But I'm using the typo3 htmlrte editor, which doesn't use CSS for setting the cell padding. Instead, it uses the attribute cellpadding, which is overridden by the CSS rule. I can't set in my CSS file a class like table.rtetable {} because the padding needs to be editable from admin.

Is there a way to unset the padding for table cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure RTE to clean tables elements attributes by using TypoScript noAttrib option.

```
RTE.default.proc.HTMLparser_db.noAttrib = th,td
```

Comment: Thanks, Fedir, but wouldn't that remove the "class" attribute for cells? I need this attribute.

Comment: You could use : RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.td.allowedAttribs = class